# Stack implementation placing codes in multiple files

Tags: c

i am trying to implement a stack by writing all its functions in a separate source file.but i get a lot of errors saying incompatible pointer type.these errors don't show up when i include the functions in the main C file.these are my files.i am new to this.help me correct them.
thank you.
my main code is

```
#include "myfunctions.h"
int main()
{
    int operation,data;
    struct stack *One = (struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    One->top = -1;
    printf("stack functionality \n");
    while(1)
    {
        if (isEmpty(One))
        {
            printf("enter 1 to push \n");
            scanf("%d",&operation);
        }
        else if (isFull(One))
        {
            printf("stack is full.enter 2 to pop or 3 to diplay \n");
            scanf("%d",&operation);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("enter 1 to push,2 to pop,3 to display 4 to exit \n");
            scanf("%d",&operation);
        }
        switch (operation)
        {
            case 1: printf("enter data to be pushed \n");
                scanf("%d",&data);
                push(One,data);
                break;
            case 2: printf("%d \n",pop(One));
                break;
            case 3: display(One);
                break;
            case 4:exit(0);
        }
    }   
}
```

stackfns code

```
#include <myfunctions.h>
bool isEmpty(struct stack *b)
{
    if(b->top == -1) return true;
    else return false;
}
bool isFull(struct stack *b)
{
    if(b->top == 9) return true;
    else return false;
}
void push(struct stack *b,int data)
{
    b->a[++(b->top)] = data;
}
int pop(struct stack *b)
{
    return (b->a[(b->top)--]);
}
void display(struct stack *b)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d ",b->a[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

header file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
extern bool isEmpty(struct stack *b);
extern bool isFull(struct stack *b);
extern void push(struct stack *b,int data);
extern int pop(struct stack *b);
extern void display(struct stack *b);
#define max_size 10
struct stack
{
    int a[max_size];
    int top;
};
```

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Comment: Gcc file1.c stackfns.c

Comment: function names are always visible via a prototype statement, so no need for the `extern` modifier.   Note: data in another file DOES need the `extern` modifier

Comment: the header file is missing the 'multiple include' guard.  That guard should be added.  suggest starting the header file with: `#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H  #define FUNCTIONS_H`   and at the end of the header file: `#endif // FUNCTIONS_H`  NOTE: header files should only be `#include`d where they are actually needed.  And they are not needed in that header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the header file you need to first decalre the struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define max_size 10
struct stack
{
    int a[max_size];
    int top;
};

extern bool isEmpty(struct stack *b);
extern bool isFull(struct stack *b);
extern void push(struct stack *b,int data);
extern int pop(struct stack *b);
extern void display(struct stack *b);
```

In addition, there is no need to expose the internal implementation of the data structure. You can do something like:

.h file:

```
typedef struct xx_t xx_t;
```

.c file:

```
struct xx_t {
    ...
};
```

Comment: In C I don't think you *need* to declare the struct before the function declarations, but it is definitely a good idea.  "Older versions of the C language didn't have prototypes, the function declarations only specified the return type and did not list the argument types."

Comment: i didn't understand the internal implementation hiding part of your answer.can you please explain

Comment: actually, the internal representation of the struct does need to be 'exposed' because the user's calling function(s) need a proper pointer to definition, so the data can be set, read, updated, etc.   IF the functions had been written as 'accessor' functions then the caller would not need the actual definition of the struct